# jQuery, show all elements by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show all elements with some class name (**string**). Something like:

```
var somevar = "apple"
$( .... select all elements with class == somevar  ).show();
```

How can it be done?

Comment: 5 answers and all the same. Must be correct :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$("." + somevar).show()

Comment: Thanks. As far as i understand there is no other way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be as simple as

```
$('.' + somevar).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("." + somevar).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var somevar = ".apple"

      $(somevar).show();

});​
```

That will show .apple

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var somevar = "apple"

      $('.' + somevar).show();

});​
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('.'+somevar).show();`